# How get an array of dates with times?

Tags: php, laravel

I need schedules table:

- id
- user_id
- reception_day (format 2023-09-21)
- time_from (11:00)
- time_to (12:00)

How can you get data by Eloquent laravel this format:

```
$arr = [
          0 => [
              '2023-09-21' => [
                  '0' => [
                      'time_from' => '8:00',
                      'time_to' => '9:00',
                  ],
                  '1' => [
                      'time_from' => '10:00',
                      'time_to' => '11:00',
                  ]
              ]
          ],
          1 => [
              '2023-09-22' => [
                  '0' => [
                      'time_from' => '8:00',
                      'time_to' => '9:00',
                  ],
                  '1' => [
                      'time_from' => '10:00',
                      'time_to' => '11:00',
                  ]
              ]
]

        ];
```

```
Schedule::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy('reception_day')
            ->get();
```

Comment: example variable $arr

Comment: changed my answer.. till get() is eloquent, after that is collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`->map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-map) from laravel to manipulate the data fetched from Eloquent queries into a collection that you can change into the keys you want.

Try this:

```
$data = Schedule::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->orderBy('reception_day')
    ->orderBy('time_from')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('reception_day')
    ->map(function ($grouped) {
        return $grouped->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'time_from' => $item->time_from,
                'time_to' => $item->time_to,
            ];
        });
    });

$arr = $data->toArray();
```